# Html page with jquery and dir=rtl appears blank on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, right-to-left

In the past few months I've witnessed a strange phenomenon, where Chrome loads a web page, and is not displaying anything until I start to scroll. At first I thought this was a problem with the site, then a glitch in some recent version of Chrome, but now I think that it is related to some conflict between jquery and rtl. The following example displays a blank page until I start to scroll:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl">
  <body>
    <h1>Blank screen test</h1>
    <div style="padding: 50%; background-color: orange;">Hey</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This does not always occur, but it happens quite consistently on my machine (e.g., ~70% of the refreshes). Make sure that the developer tools are closed - for some reason it does not happen when they are open.

Removing the `dir="rtl"` prevents this from happening.

Removing the `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>` also prevents this from happening.

Not sure what to make of it. Does anybody else see this happening? Any ideas how to solve this?

(BTW, I'm using Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) on Mac OS 10.12.5)

[Here is a link to an example page](http://roysharon.com/blanktest.html).

[Here is how it looks before I start scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyUU6.png), and [here is how it looks the instance scrolling starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUWro.png).

Comment: Please link an example page with your issue.

Comment: Added a link to an example page.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce this at all. The example works just fine. I am using the same Chrome version as you.

Comment: I can totally reproduce this locally with chrome 58.0.3029.110 (same version as OP)
The [`dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) attribute shouldn't lead to any 'unexpected' behaviour in any modern browser, so I guess the problem lies with jQuery. A [quick search](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dir&type=) makes me guess if those tests will fail under chrome when the `<html dir="">` is set to `rtl`.

Comment: @RoySharon works fine for me as well. you could try checking if any chrome extensions are causing the problem or either if hardware acceleration is causing the problem.

Comment: Seems like a Heisenbug

Comment: My answer was a bit premature ;) interestingly this happens also when you remove the `dir` attribute completely and try to set the direction via css `html { direction: rtl; }`

Comment: Works fine. Absolutely no issues.

Comment: Yes works fine no issues i can see direct orange background without scrolling

Comment: Works fine for me. But I know the problem with blank pages. I see them from time to time until I scroll (doesn't matter which website).

Comment: @RoySharon can you send a screenshot of how the page appears on your end ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek added links to screen captures of before and after scrolling.

Comment: I suggest try with the basics, make sure you've cleared cache and there are no stored cookies. Sometimes they are a cause of trouble.

Comment: @Ashish Bahl apart from not working (I tested), this is not a practical solution. I cannot expect all of my site's users to clear their caches and have no stored cookies.

Comment: I have tested that with chromium (same version) on Ubuntu and it works fine. What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS 10.12.5

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it on the same OS and Chrome version. Have you tried opening in an anonymous tab? It can also be caused by Chrome plugins you might have enabled.

Comment: Tried it in incognito with no plugins, still blank until scroll.

Comment: @RoySharon I can afford couple of hours on team viewer to examine the exact issue on your side, and help solving it. Please feel free to add me on skype: prollygeek

Comment: It looks like [issue 707542](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=707542) reported in Chromium. Another discussion on that problem (or a very similar one) is found in [that post from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184377/chrome-shows-blank-page-on-rtl-language-site-until-window-is-resized).

Comment: @ConnorsFan good catch! Thanks. Indeed looks like the same issue. This was marked as fixed on April 21st 2017, so according to the Chromium release schedule (https://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar) it should be released in version 60, which was scheduled for May 25th 2017 (stable version on July 26). I will download this version and see if the bug still persists.

Comment: @ProllyGeek Thanks much! Greatly appreciated. I want to check version 60 first, and then decide how to proceed. But thank you very much, what a great community!

Comment: Seems like this issue was solved in version 59 of Chrome. I've downloaded the beta (59.0.3071.82 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)) and I can confirm that the blanktest url above renders okay. Tried it about 50 times and it works just fine. So the bug may be solved. Thanks @ConnorsFan for the pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute `dir` can be overriden by CSS `direction: rtl;`, when it comes to content presentation:

As the directionality of the text is semantically related, I suggest you add `dir='rtl'` in Javascript when jQuery is loaded. That way, `dir` is not interfering with jQuery when the page is loading.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Blank screen test</h1>
    <div style="padding: 50%; background-color: orange;">Hey</div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() { $('html').attr('dir', 'rtl'); });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! It works on my machine. I ask other readers to test this and see if it is also working for them: http://roysharon.com/blanktest2.html

Comment: Thank you for editing the snippet. But I think you need to add the CSS in the example. This would avoid having the text being on the left while the JS is loading, and ensure that your content has the right direction.

Comment: Well, adding the css causes the problem to appear again. This is why I took it out here: http://roysharon.com/blanktest2.html

Comment: To avoid showing the page when the dir is still ltr, we can add `style="display:none"` to the html tag, and then change the onready func to `$(function() { $('html').attr('dir', 'rtl').show(); })`

Comment: I see, so it's a problem with the css property, not the html attribute. I actually tried with all the browsers I have (Mac and Windows VMs), but I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Quick question, have you tried putting `dir='rtl';` in the `<body>` instead for the `<html>` tag ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145515/discussion-between-j-printemps-and-roy-sharon).

Comment: It seems that Chrome version 59 includes a fix to this issue (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=707542). Just downloaded the beta and the blanktest page renders fine. Since @j-printemps was the first to propose a working workaround, I'm accepting his answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My best guess, unfortunately, is that the direction attribute might mess with jQuery's traversing functionality when loaded. Might be some hints on that in [this repo search](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dir&type=).

One workaround is to set the attribute or css rule after loading the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            document.documentElement.dir = 'rtl';
            // or
            document.documentElement.style.direction = 'rtl';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Blank screen test</h1>
    <div style="padding: 50%; background-color: orange;">Hey</div>
    <script src="./blanktest_files/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This workaround does not affect the blank page behavior. :-(

Comment: I've checked the jquery repo pointer - none of the results there seem to have any bearing on the blank page problem. My guess is that it relates to the way Chrome renders the page and not to jquery. I.e., Chrome loaded the gun, jquery just pressed the trigger. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `async` attribute solved the problem for me (not like there is much left to parse as you put the `script` at the end).

So replace

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" async></script>
```

Comment: This indeed makes the bug less frequent, but it still appears around 30% of the time on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Insert code in onload:

```
<body onload="document.body.setAttribute('dir', 'rtl')">
```

dir attribute could be utilized in others elements.
Exemple:

```
<h1 dir="tld">TESTE</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is essentially the same as j-printemps' solution above.

Comment: You are right re onload != .ready, but the idea behind your proposal is to cause a redraw of the page at some point after the page had loaded, which is the essence of @j-printemps' accepted solution. In any case, thanks for posting an answer!